# TypeError: only size-1 arrays (I am trying to print most similar words)

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, spacy

## How to return similar words?

I have such Python code, this code should simply prints array of given similar word e,g, "japan"

### code:

```py
import spacy
import numpy as np

# Load the larger pre-trained English model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

# Get the vector for "japan"
word_vec = nlp("japan").vector

# Reshape the word_vec array to have a second dimension of size 1
word_vec = np.reshape(word_vec, (1, -1))

# Find the 3 most similar words to "japan"
most_similar = nlp.vocab.vectors.most_similar(word_vec, n=3)

# Extract the words from the most_similar list
similar_words = [nlp.vocab.strings[similar[0]] for similar in most_similar]

print(similar_words)
```

### Error

```
user@users-MacBook training % python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/project/training/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    similar_words = [nlp.vocab.strings[similar[0]] for similar in most_similar]
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/user/project/training/main.py", line 17, in <listcomp>
    similar_words = [nlp.vocab.strings[similar[0]] for similar in most_similar]
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "spacy/strings.pyx", line 156, in spacy.strings.StringStore.__getitem__
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

---

When I print `most_similar`

```
 (array([
   [ 6726951824429389069, 
     10815251124955538419,  
     4763767604223487472
   ]
  ],
  dtype=uint64), 
 array([
    [10959, 
     11621,
     16082]
     ], dtype=int32), array([[1.    , 0.6241, 0.575 ]], dtype=float32))
```

I get this, but I cannot convert this to word

How can I fix it?

Comment: Full error message please. Most likely some parameter shou,d be a scalar rather than an array.

Comment: `similar` is a (1,3) array, so `similar[0]` is (3,) shale, and can't be used as index

Answer (score 0):

`similar[0]` to `similar[0][0]` and it'll be fixed